# JQueryUI: Force page to use default jquery Datepicker function and not from other extensions

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, datepicker

I load a page with few default scripts from a bundle

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

Now, I am using bootstrap datepicker across my app. But, I am trying to avoid it on this specific .cshtml page.

```
$( "#DateOfBirth" ).datepicker();
```

For ex, the above line should use jQueryUI datepicker and not Bootstrap.

can I somehow ignore bootstrap files on this page or force code to point to use jqueryui?

Comment: You need a bit more detail in your question. Why can't you just remove that line of code on that page?

Comment: Its using a layout page with css and styling. That layout page is used across app. I can create a new layout just for this file. But just wondered if its possible to ignore jqueryui extension method and rather use original/default method.